# Querying for the list of windows in the same column/row of the current window

Tags: vim-windows, layout

Consider a window layout as this (which I've set up esentially at random).

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬────────┐
│       │       │       │        │
│   x   │   y   │   z   │        │
│       │       │       │        │
├───────┴───────┴───────┤        │
│                       │        │
│           u           │        │
│                       │        │
├───────────────────────┤        │
│                       │        │
│           v           │        │
│                       │        │
├───────────────────────┴────────┤
│                                │
│                                │
└────────────────────────────────┘
```

Is there a way, if the cursor is in any of `x`, `y`, or `z`, to retrieve the list of all three windows?

The reason I think it is possible, in principle, is that there's one command that has to query for that list of windows, that is <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.

Similarly, I think it would be possible to make the same query when the cursor is in `u` or `v`, in which case the answer would be a list of `u`, `v`, and `[x,z,y]`.

In this case too, the error `E443` tells me that the query was done and gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [winlayout()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winlayout%28%29) function to get information about the layout of the windows (rows and columns).

With the above window layout, this function will return (something similar to the following):

> ['col', [['row', [['col', [['row', [['leaf', 1007], ['leaf', 1006], ['leaf', 1005]]], ['leaf', 1004], ['leaf', 1003]]], ['leaf', 1002]]], ['leaf', 1000]]]

The numbers in the output are the [window identifiers](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#window-ID).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Vimscript:

```
function! GetSimilarWindowsInDirection(dir)
    let prev_winnr = winnr()
    let orig_w = winwidth(0)
    let orig_h = winheight(0)

    let similar_windows = []

    if a:dir=='j' || a:dir == 'k'
        let match_prop = 'width'
    elseif a:dir == 'l' || a:dir == 'h'
        let match_prop = 'height'
    else
        return
    endif

    " Check Nth window in the direction given for similar width
    let N = 1
    while v:true
        let new_winnr = winnr(N.a:dir)

        if new_winnr == prev_winnr
            " We hit the edge, no more windows to find
            break
        endif

        if match_prop == 'width'
            let new_w = winwidth(new_winnr)
            if new_w != orig_w | break |endif

        elseif match_prop == 'height'
            let new_h = winheight(new_winnr)
            if new_h != orig_h | break |endif

        endif

        call add(similar_windows, new_winnr)

        let prev_winnr = new_winnr
        let N+=1
    endwhile

    return similar_windows

endfunction

function! GetSimilarWindows(type)
    let similar_windows = [winnr()]

    if a:type == 'col'
        call extend(similar_windows, GetSimilarWindowsInDirection('j'))
        call extend(similar_windows, GetSimilarWindowsInDirection('k'))
    elseif a:type == 'row'
        call extend(similar_windows, GetSimilarWindowsInDirection('h'))
        call extend(similar_windows, GetSimilarWindowsInDirection('l'))

    endif

    return sort(similar_windows,'n')

endfunction
```

With the cursor in window y in your diagram:
`echo GetSimilarWindows('row')` will return `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Instead of jumping to the neighbor window to get the window number, you can use the winnr() https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winnr%28%29 function with the 'h' 'j', 'k' or 'l'  argument to get the left/below/above/right window number. You can also prefix this  argument with a number to get the n'th neighbor window.

Comment: I edited my Vimscript to a better algorith with help from your comment too.  

In a 3x3 grid, my previous code wouldn't identify a complete row or column.  I changed the requirement to equal width for columns and equal height for rows.